# Pass FieldName as a Parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, anonymous-function

I'm not quite sure what I'm attempting to do is called, so I'm struggling to find any clues from google.

I have a couple of methods with the same logic in them, the only thing that differs is the property they are using on an object.

```
class Foo
{
   public int A(Bar bar)
   {
      return bar.A * 2;
   }

   public int B(Bar bar)
   {
      return bar.B * 2;
   }

   public int C(Bar bar)
   {
      return bar.C * 2;
   }
}

class Bar
{
   public int A;
   public int B;
   public int C;
}
```

Instead of the three separate methods in `Foo` I want one, with a signature that looks more like

```
public int X(Bar bar, ??? x)
{
   return bar.x * 2;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you have to split up the call in object and field and not just pass the bar.X to the method? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
internal class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        var bar = new Bar {A = 1, B = 2, C = 3};
        Console.WriteLine(new Foo().X(bar, it => it.A));
        Console.WriteLine(new Foo().X(bar, it => it.B));

        // or introduce a "constant" somewhere
        Func<Bar, int> cFieldSelector = it => it.C;
        Console.WriteLine(new Foo().X(bar, cFieldSelector));
    }
}

internal class Foo {
    // Instead of using a field by name, give it a method to select field you want.
    public int X(Bar bar, Func<Bar, int> fieldSelector) {
        return fieldSelector(bar) * 2;
    }

    public int A(Bar bar) {
        return bar.A * 2;
    }

    public int B(Bar bar) {
        return bar.B * 2;
    }

    public int C(Bar bar) {
        return bar.C * 2;
    }
}

internal class Bar {
    public int A;
    public int B;
    public int C;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

I misread the question the first time, my bad.

You can do this with Reflection:

```
public int Method(Bar bar, string propertyName)
{
   var prop = typeof(Bar).GetProperty(propertyName);
   int value = (int)prop.GetValue(bar,null);
   return value * 2;
}
```

Then, you call it like this:

```
Method(bar,"A");
```

Just noticed that in your example, the 3 variables in Bar are public instance variables. I'm assuming that you just did this for your sample, but if this is in fact the case in your real class, use Rex M's approach.

Comment: While this is possible it can cause runtime errors because the compiler has no way to check if the passed property does exist. I would think about changing the design.

Comment: Note that `nameof` (since C# 6.0) can help avoid issue mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider using an anonymous delegate to get your value instead.

```
public int X(Bar bar, Func<Bar,int> getIt)
{
   return getIt(bar) * 2;
}
```

Then call it like:

```
var x = X(mybar, x=>x.A);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using reflection. It will have some performance impact

Answer (score 0):

you can use the PropertyInfo class to retrieve the desired property via reflection: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6099345.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public int X(Bar bar, string target)
{
    object value = bar.GetType().GetField(target, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(bar);
    return (int)value * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using reflection. Here's some simple code to achieve the effect.

```
using System.Reflection;    

public int X(Bar bar, FieldInfo x)
{
    return (int)x.GetValue(bar) * 2;
}
```

Now, you can call X by first getting the FieldInfo for one of the fields on Bar.

```
Bar b = new Bar();
b.A = 20;
b.B = 30;
b.C = 40;

FieldInfo fieldA = typeof(Bar).GetField("A");
int result = X(b, fieldA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FieldInfo

```
BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
FieldInfo field = typeof(Bar).GetField("A", flags);
```

field.SetValue(..) to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

you could use an extension method.. for the example you posted.. but i guess that your example is just a simplified version of some more complex code.

```
public static class IntExt
{
    //use Bar.A.Double();
    public int Double(this int value)
    {
        return value * 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an enumeration and pass it into the function to determine which to use?  It seems reflection is kinda going west around the world to take a step to the right...

```
class Foo
{
   public enum BarChoice { a,b,c };
   public int x(Bar bar, BarChoice bc)
   {
     switch(bc) 
     {
       case a:
         return bar.A * 2;
       case b:
         return bar.B * 2;
       case c:
         return bar.C * 2;
     }
     return int.MinValue;
   }
}
```

Then your call would be

```
 Foo f = new foo();
 Bar b = new Bar();
 f.x(b, Foo.BarChoice.a);
 f.x(b, Foo.BarChoice.b);
 f.x(b, Foo.BarChoice.c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ref` keyword:

```
class Foo
{
    public void A(ref int fieldRef)
    {
        fieldRef *= 2;
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public int A;
    public int B;
    public int C;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bar = new Bar { A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 };
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.A(ref bar.A);
        foo.A(ref bar.B);
        foo.A(ref bar.C);

        Console.WriteLine(bar.A); // 2
        Console.WriteLine(bar.B); // 4
        Console.WriteLine(bar.C); // 6
    }
}
```

I've changed a bit your example which was not realistic (as @Jonas Elfström said, you can simply pass the value in this case). This one show that you can change the value of the field.